# Automate Adobe PDF web forms (XFA) using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to automate Adobe PDF web forms (XFA) using selenium web driver ? How to inspect elements in order to input text or click submit button in PDF forms ? These pdf forms are only supported by IE and no other browsers

Comment: Selenium Webdriver works only for web application, it requires a DOM to spawn !!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Webdriver can only perform operations on DOM.
Can you right click on the form and see if view source option is coming?If not,then i don't think you can input anything on your Adobe PDF using Selenium Webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

You can't automate PDF file but yes you can verify any text any content in PDF file. You can try below code if it met your requirement

Try below code:-

```
  public void ReadPDF() throws Exception {
    URL TestURL = new URL("http://www.axmag.com/download/pdfurl-guide.pdf");

    BufferedInputStream TestFile = new BufferedInputStream(TestURL.openStream());
    PDFParser TestPDF = new PDFParser(TestFile);
    TestPDF.parse();
    String TestText = new PDFTextStripper().getText(TestPDF.getPDDocument());

    Assert.assertTrue(TestText.contains("Open the setting.xml, you can see it is like this"));

    }
```

Download libraries :- https://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html

Hope it will help you :)